# How to use \autocite with biblatex-apa?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm trying to use `\autocite` feature with biblatex-apa, but it seems that the `\autocite` macro is not defined in biblatex-apa 5.7 (and biblatex 2.5). Example code follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % using XeLaTeX
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Husserl1962,
  author = {Edmund Husserl},
  title = {Die {Krisis} der europäischen {Wissenschaften} und die
    transzendentale {Phänomenologie}},
  publisher = {Martinus Nijhoff},
  year = {1962},
  address = {Haag},
  series = {Husserliana},
  edition = {2},
  type = {Husserliana VI}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Phenomenology is always fun \autocite{Husserl1962}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This results in the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.25 Phenomenology is always fun \autocite
                                          {Husserl1962}.
```

A quick fix would of course be to add `\let\autocite=\parencite` before \begin{document}, but I guess that should rather be a part of apa.cbx or something.

Comment: A quick fix would of course be to add `\let\autocite=\parencite` before `\begin{document}`, but I guess that should rather be a part of apa.cbx or something.

Comment: I edited your question to add your comment.

Comment: This will be added in version 5.9 shortly when biblatex 2.6 and biber 1.6 are released.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wanted to add that the `\let\autocite=\parencite` does not work for me; found another solution which does. While calling biblatex add an option autocite=inline

like so:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
```

Have pasted the complete invocation as I don't know enough latex to figure out whether any other option is necessary or not.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it; redefining `\autocite` with `\let` is a dirty hack.

Answer (score 1):

PLK wrote:

> This will be added in version 5.9 shortly when biblatex 2.6 and biber 1.6 are released.